Wired connection repeatedly getting disconnected
My PC (runing Ubuntu server 16.04) is connecting to Router Port (Cisco 800M) working fine but when connecting to a switch (Dlink DGS 1210-28) it repeatedly getting disconnected. The difference I noticed Speed 1000mbps to 10 mbps. Previously this pc is working fine. Some other pc (Ubuntu 20.04) are also facing this issue while some are working fine.

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's standard support life thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm  This is community support; 16.04 is EOSS thus out of community support.

This is a network hardware issue. Your server has a network card that is negotiating a 1Gbps connection correctly with the Cisco 800M router. This means that the network interface and the cables work fine.
However the Dlink DGS1210 does not negotiate the full 1Gbps and instead uses 10Mbps. It does this because an ethernet cable consist of 4 wire pairs which each can reach 250Mbps, but instead it is not even negotiating 100Mbps, but the 10Mbps which means one wire pair is functioning. One broken wire/connector could cause this, but also you can force the negotiation link to certain speeds. Since the DLink is a managed switch, you should be able to see if the port is set to limit to 10Mbps or not, you can ofcourse also try one of the other ports.
From Ubuntu you can do some troubleshooting with mii-tool or ethtool, to see what has been negotiated, but is this not a problem on the serverside
 mii-tool eth1
 eth1: negotiated 1000baseT-FD flow-control, link ok

